# CSS3 animation on li remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a subtle fade effect as `li` gets removed from the `ul`. I added this piece of CSS:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
```

on my `li`

However, when I remove that `li` using `$(this).remove();` the li gets removed but there is no animation seen.

What am I missing?

**EDIT** I don't want to use Jquery fadeOut. I want to be able to use CSS3 animations.

Comment: I want to use remove and still have animation in CSS3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! You just need some magic of [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event.

```js
// start transition animation on click
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).addClass('removed');
});

// remove li on transition animation end
$(document).on('transitionend', '.removed', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.removed {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
    <li>menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! And I made small plugin for you http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/v3dwpz6w/.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **CSS** way of doing it.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/moc1jt05/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>hellow world 1!!</li>
    <li>hellow world 2!!</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    opacity: 1;
}
li.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```js
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).hide(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove()
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to use CSS3 and not hide because fade is just an example CSS3 can do much more.

Answer (score 0):

Try fading out and then removing the element:

```
$(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
    <li>menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

with JS

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
    //You can also use time delay
    //$(this).slideUp(1000);
});
```

fiddle link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdbfmx03/)

Answer (score 0):

**See the Code Snippet - Below** -

You should use [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) for animation effect

```js
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove()
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
    <li>click</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Jack - See the code snippet , you can use fadeOut() for effect